# The Cardinality of infinite series of natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$,and the map $F(a_1,a_2,a_3...) = {p_1}^{-a_1}{p_2}^{-a_2}{p_3}^{-a_3}...$

Where $p_i$ is the ith prime (chosen by the axiom of choice).  Why isn't this map one to one on the the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Where do the elements $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ come from?

Comment: They're natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you choose $a_i$ big enough such that for some $ε>0$ all $p_i^{-a_i} ≤ 1-ε < 1$ you have $F(a_1, …) = 0$. So $F$ can not be injective.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the elements $a_i$ are natural numbers (including zero).

If there exists such a $N$ that $a_i=0$ for all $i>N$, then the product is obviously a rational number.

If such a $N$ does not exists, the product, if you define
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i} = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{i=1}^Np_i^{a_i},$$

will actually equal zero. Therefore, the mapping only covers some of the rational numbers (not even all of them) and $0$.

Comment: The mapping can cover $2/3$ ?

Comment: It can? I would like to see proof of this. After all, if only one of the $a_i$ is non-zero, the value assigned by the mapping is smaller than $p_i^{a_i}$ which is less than or equal to $\frac12$

Comment: I agree with your answer : "the mapping only covers some of the rational numbers (*not even all of them*) [emphasis added]"; so I'm asking if a simple example of rational *not* covered is $2/3$ ... Thanks. If I have $p_1=2$, with $a_1=1$ (all others $0$) I have $1/2$; with $a_2=1$ (all others $0$) I have $1/3$, so there are no other chances ...

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Yes, in fact, the mapping covers nothing above $\frac12$ and nothing between $\frac13$ and $\frac12$ and so . It covers only all numbers $\frac1n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes, the mapping covers only $1$, $1/2$, ... $1/n$, ... ; may we say that "converges" to the "condensation point" $0$.